# SQL , INGRES : replace by blank after some char

Tags: sql, ingres

```
days: char (31)
period : char (31)

days : 1234567891234567891234567891234
period: AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCD
```

I want to replace everything by `*` after the 20th character

```
days : 12345678912345678912***********
period:AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB***********
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
select 
  rpad(substr(days,1,20),length(days),'*'),
  rpad(substr(period,1,20),length(period),'*')
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server :

```
 DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (DAYS VARCHAR(MAX), PERIOD VARCHAR(MAX))
insert into @table values 
('1234567891234567891234567891234', 'AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCD')

SELECT SUBSTRING(DAYS,1,20)+REPLICATE('*',LEN(DAYS)- 20),
SUBSTRING(PERIOD ,1,20)+REPLICATE('*',LEN(PERIOD)- 20) FROM @TABLE
```